# Need assistance to write a small program to Multiply Cycles up to n elements and k multiplicities

Tags: c++, python-3.x, math, cycle

i'm trying to write a program that Multiplies Cycles to concatenate between permutations and i'm not sure how to define it, also not sure what to use it's either in C++ or Python.

If it's in C++ i should probably use `std::string` to hold the numbers in a specific order like so:

```
(1 2 3 ... n)
```

If it's python i should probably use List to hold everything in it like so:

```
["(", "1", " ", "2", " ", "3", " ", "...", " ", "n" ")"]
```

from the user input.

I will also need to search if a number from the right factor exists in the left one
and to define some conditions like if it brought me to the same number i will need to close the cycle product.

```
(1 2 3 ... n)*(1 2 3 ... k)
```

But that's where it becomes tricky, how to define the multiplication itself.

I really need some advice here..

Comment: I am still not sure what you expect to be the result of `(1 2 3 ... n)*(1 2 3 ... k)`. Could you give an example?

Comment: of course, lets say i need to multiply / concatenate two cycles :

Comment: (1 3 2 4 5)*(3 1 4 2 5) = (1 5 2)

Comment: here is an example video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gGir2mwNrbo

Comment: How have you got (1 5 2) ?

Comment: @MBo the Video is quite helpful to understand the locig ;)

Comment: it's all in the video. you start with chosen cycle on the right and write it in the result and search the closest to it in the left factor and write it in the result until you finished all numbers in the cycle or until you reached the same number as the start number. if you finished a cycle and there are still numbers left than you open another cicle in the result and multiply it by the previous one..

Comment: Using `std::string` for storing numbers is an obscenely terrible idea. C++'s analog for Python lists is `std::vector`, which has similar semantics.

Comment: if you could choose, which language would you use to write it?

Answer (score 0):

C++ allows you to overload the multiplication operator for your own classes. Here is an example ([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/D5KAYy))

```
#include <iostream>

struct myInt
{
    int value;

    myInt(int v = 0) : value(v) {};

    myInt operator*(const myInt& b) const
    {        
        // complex logic here...
        return myInt(value*b.value);
    }
};


int main()
{
    myInt two(2), three(3), result;
    result = two*three;
    std::cout << result.value << std::endl;
}
```

Alternatively you can define the binary `operator*` outside the class:

```
myInt operator*(const myInt &a, const myInt& b)
{
    return myInt(a*b);
}
```

However, to implement the complex logic is up you. But this definitely solves your problem.

For your problem, you should not store the numbers as string.
Create a class which holds a vector of integers and define the multiplication operator for this class.

```
struct myCycle
{

std::vector <unsigned int> data;

myCycle() = default;
myCycle(const std::vector<unsigned int> d) : data(d) {}

myCycle operator*(const myCycle &b) const 
{
    myCycle result;
    // do the multiplication and write to result.
    return myCycle;
}

};
```

Comment: ok that seems legit, i know the basics of operator overloading. As for the inputs, the user should insert the inputs like so (1 3 2 4 5)*(3 1 4 2 5)  or (1 3 2 4 5)*(4 2 5) *(2 3 1) you can give as many as you like and not all numbers have to appear, that just means that the number will keep going left until it finds himself and look for the closest to it from the right. if the number does not exist but the size defined for n numbers than the number just goes to itself and doesn't appear on the result.

Comment: Ok, something like that should probably be passed as string, but then you need a function parser, which goes through the expression, constructs the `myCycle` objects and then calls the corresponding operations `operator*`. There exist numerous ways how to parse this expression. You can for instance use `std::regex` to get the content within a parenthesis. And `std::find` to search for `*`. That is, read the string, parse it, create the `myCycle` objects and do the multiplication.

Comment: never used it before but i want to try. but wasn't this all easier with a vector of strings? or a vector of sets? my original idea was using getline and stringstream and than to store it accordingly and do the search/find functions.

Comment: Well, I just showed you a possible way. At the end its up to you. But for math operations it seems natural to me to convert the input to numbers and not use strings. I haven't looked into the details, so maybe set would be more suited than a vector, but I'd still prefer a set with integers.

Comment: You right, i will try and see what works best for me. maybe doing it your way will be enough and i won't need unnecessary complications in the code, we'll see.